# How do I change a condition within a loop, but only after the first iteration?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm creating a simple model which calculates the minimum fixed monthly payment required to pay off a credit card balance within 12 months.

My code:

```
balance = 3329             # starting balance
annualInterestRate = 0.2   # yearly interest rate
minFixedPayment = 0        # initiate a minimum monthly payment of 0

while balance > 0:
    minFixedPayment = minFixedPayment + 10
    for i in range(1,13,1):
        unpaidBalance = balance - minFixedPayment
        balance = unpaidBalance + ((annualInterestRate/12) * unpaidBalance)
        i=i+1
print(round(minFixedPayment,2))
```

I added the "minFixedPayment" increment BEORE the for loop so that it keeps incrementing until it finds a value where balance is <= 0 at the end of month 12. I know this is wrong since it will compute the first iteration with minFixedPayment = 10, not 0. Is there a better way to arrange this?

I've tried adding the

```
minFixedPayment = minFixedPayment + 10
```

statement to the end of the loop, like this:

```
while balance > 0:
    for i in range(1,13,1):
        unpaidBalance = balance - minFixedPayment
        balance = unpaidBalance + ((annualInterestRate/12) * unpaidBalance)
        i=i+1
    minFixedPayment = minFixedPayment + 10 # moved this to after the loop
print(round(minFixedPayment,2))
```

but that makes the while loop run forever (why?).

Is there a better way to approach this?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why not start with  `minFixedPayment = -10` and print/return `max(0, round(minFixedPayment,2))`?

Comment: Also, you're calculating a 20% interest loan on 3329 and making ten dollar payments, its highly conceivable you'd never pay it off.

Comment: General words of advice: lose the while loop and set an upper bound on the  run-time or iterations. Next, to be robust, you'll probably wanna check for when your balance drops below a single cent, not below zero as @ChihebNexus is pointing out.

Comment: @trincot clever! but still makes the while loop run forever :(

Comment: @RYS Just sample values, doing this for a class :) I'll try to frame the approach differently with a set upper bound on the loop, thanks!

Comment: Sure, but if the interest is always higher than the payment, it'll run forever right?

Comment: It is a bit strange that for 12 consecutive months you want the payment to be zero. With such a high yearly rate (20%!!), the amount will be near $4000 after 12 months. And then the payment will be just $10 per month for the next 12 months, while the interest will be more than $60 per month. The next year the downpayment will be $20, but the interest will have increased more ($80), etc. That's not a reasonable loan plan.

Comment: @trincot I want the payment to start at 0 (arbitrary) and have the while loop increase that number and retry the for loop until it finds the minimum monthly payment required to pay off the entire balance by the end of month 12. This is for a class :)

Comment: And it should be a multiple of 10? Also, why would you even try with 0? With 0 no-one can pay off any non-zero loan, not even if the interest is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- As your intention is to try with different payment amounts, you should reset the balance to its original value with each attempt. Without that, you can get into an infinite loop with an ever increasing balance. In order to be able to reset the balance, you'll need to store it in a second name as well.
- You should not increase `i` with `i=i+1`. That is already taken care of with the `for` loop.

Here is the suggested code:

```
loan = balance = 3329      # starting balance, use two names so you can restart
annualInterestRate = 0.2   # yearly interest rate
minFixedPayment = -10      # initiate a minimum monthly payment

monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate/12 # avoid doing this repeatedly

while balance > 0:
    minFixedPayment = minFixedPayment + 10
    balance = loan # start from scratch
    for i in range(1,13):
        unpaidBalance = balance - minFixedPayment
        balance = unpaidBalance + monthlyInterestRate * unpaidBalance

print(round(minFixedPayment,2))
```

Comment: That worked!!! :))) Thank you. I think the key was restarting the balance value after every loop, as well as setting initial minFixPayment to -10. Clever!
Thank you for the clean up as well, I've been staring at it for a while and forgot some redundant code there.

Answer (score 1):

For your interest, here is a more sophisticated solver:

```
from functools import partial
from math import ceil

def diff(fn, x, h=0.001):
    """
    Numerically differentiate fn at x
    """
    return (fn(x + h) - fn(x)) / h

def newton_solver(fn, target_y, initial_x, max_reps=100, max_err=0.01):
    """
    Find a value for x such that fn(x) == target_y (+/- max_err)
    """
    x = initial_x
    for _ in range(max_reps):
        err = fn(x) - target_y
        if abs(err) <= max_err:
            # found a good enough solution
            return x
        else:
            # first-order correction to reduce error
            x -= err / diff(fn, x)
    raise ValueError("solver failed to converge")

def final_balance(fixed_payment, initial_balance, period_rate, num_periods):
    """
    Calculate the final balance on a fixed payment plan
    """
    balance = initial_balance
    for _ in range(num_periods):
        balance = (balance - fixed_payment) * (1. + period_rate)
    return balance

def round_up_to_next_cent(amt):
    return ceil(amt * 100.) / 100.

def main():
    initial_balance = 3329.
    annual_interest = 0.2

    # bind arguments to create a single-argument function to pass to newton_solver
    my_final_balance = partial(final_balance, initial_balance = initial_balance, period_rate = annual_interest / 12, num_periods = 12)

    # initial guess - in total you will pay about half a year's interest
    monthly_payment_guess = initial_balance * (1. + annual_interest * 0.5) / 12

    # solve to find accurate value
    monthly_payment = newton_solver(my_final_balance, 0., monthly_payment_guess)
    monthly_payment = round_up_to_next_cent(monthly_payment)

    # and report the result
    print("A fixed monthly payment of ${:0.2f} results in a final balance of ${:0.2f}".format(monthly_payment, my_final_balance(monthly_payment)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

which produces

```
A fixed monthly payment of $303.33 results in a final balance of $-0.07
```

Answer (score 0):

add a flag variable to control if balance is changed. Another way could be to check if balance is changed. (`if balance != original_balance: ...`)
e.g.

```
balance = 3329             # starting balance
annualInterestRate = 0.2   # yearly interest rate
minFixedPayment = 0        # initiate a minimum monthly payment of 0
change_flag = 0
while balance > 0:
    if change_flag: minFixedPayment = minFixedPayment + 10
    change_flag = 1
    for i in range(1,13,1):
        unpaidBalance = balance - minFixedPayment
        balance = unpaidBalance + ((annualInterestRate/12) * unpaidBalance)
        i=i+1
print(round(minFixedPayment,2))
```

Comment: try it with smaller balance, e.g. 1000